# an issue was found indicating you may need to update to the latest version of the sdk and rebuild your app

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

Getting this error when trying to submit to the new itunesConnect store

```
an issue was found indicating you may need to update to the latest version of the sdk and rebuild your app
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrading to Xcode 6.1 from Xcode 6.0 - it works.